# ListBox.ScrollIntoView works only after delay

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a problem with a `listbox.ScrollIntoView` method - it does not work. Here is the code snippet:

```
// the listbox is binded to a "Thumbnails" property
this.Thumbnails = new VirtualizableCollection<RecordingThumbnailItem>(this.thumbnailsProvider) { ItemsStep = this.ThumbnailsStep };
this.listBox.ScrollIntoView(this.Thumbnails[thumbnailToSelect]);
```

I've noticed that if I call `ScrollIntoView` a little bit later (for instance in 500 milliseconds after the source for a binding was defined) everything works. So I suppose that `ScrollIntoView` should be invoked after the control will obtain some specific state; 
if so, how can I detect it? Maybe using some event? 
Eventually, I just need to enforce my horizontal listbox to show the last item in a right end, but not in a left as usual. Maybe some other approach exists?

Comment: I have no delay when calling the `ScrollIntoView` method. Perhaps your delay is caused by the initialisation of your `VirtualizableCollection`? Can you provide workable code that features your problem that we can load into a new project and test for you?

Comment: There is some misunderstanding. ScrollIntoView does not work at all in my case. But if I make some delay (Thread sleep) between Thumbnails initialization and ScrollIntoView invokation - then it works

Comment: The problem that we have @vklu4itesvet, is that for you, it does not work and for us, it does. I therefore suggest that you have something in your code that is stopping it from working. If you would like us to help you find a solution, then you will have to show us the relevant code. It could be not working for any number of reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the views that represent each of the items hasn't been created yet, so the view *can't* be scrolled onto the screen.

You can use the `Dispatcher` to queue up the `ScrollIntoView()` call with a lower priority than the UI, which gives the UI time to generate the views.

Try this:

```
this.Thumbnails = new VirtualizableCollection<RecordingThumbnailItem>(this.thumbnailsProvider) { ItemsStep = this.ThumbnailsStep };
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
    new Action(() => this.listBox.ScrollIntoView(this.Thumbnails[thumbnailToSelect])
);
```

You might need to substitute `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` with `Application.Current.Dispatcher` if the CurrentDispatcher happens to be one other than the UI one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One remark in my case DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle

Comment: Yeah, the spot in my code where this is still has a comment to the effect of "hope this works every time". In my case it has, it would be good to get confirmation from an expert, but it does seem to work to solve this issue.

Comment: need to tell testers about it)

Comment: On WinRT, await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync((args)=> { ... });  seems to work pretty well, too.  Thanks!