# Auto scroll to the end of a Textblock in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to view the content of a textblock that was added last. It means I want to auto scroll to the end and view the hidden content when I add more text... just like in Windows calculator.

In the calculator when I enter more numbers it shows only the numbers entered last. Previously entered numbers are hidden when there is not enough space. I want to do the exact same thing..

Can someone please help me?

Comment: A textbox has this functionality built in. Is it possible to use this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a TextBox, as opposed to a TextBlock? The default behavior for a TextBox is to show the most recent text as more text is entered.

```
Window x:Class="textboxscrolltest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="75" Height="25"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Not working for me. I am using it as console and appending text to it from logs. but its not scrolling automatically

Comment: The question is about TextBlock as main stream output UI element where scrolling is very appreciated

Answer (score 17):

I don't think `TextBlock`s can scroll. You can put the `TextBlock` in a `ScrollViewer`.

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
        A bunch of text
    </TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code-behind:

```
MyScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
```

It appears that if you have multiple TextBlocks in a ListBox, you cannot get access very easily to it's ScrollViewer to accomplish the same thing. If you are doing this, change your ListBox to an ItemsControl and put that into a ScrollViewer. I think you'll lose selection ability though.

If you do need to use a ListBox, then you can get the view that belongs to the last item and call the ListBox's ScrollIntoView() method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946954/make-listview-scrollintoview-scroll-the-item-into-the-center-of-the-listview-c) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806117/listbox-scrollintoview-works-only-after-delay/17810115#17810115) for a little bit about that, but you might have to do a little more research.